# Atlasboard gives me 500 in the GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, atlasboard

GET /widgets/time?_=1461148321996 **500** 16.361 ms - 43

I simply dont get why that happens only with my default widgets the demo widgets get loaded but not my own.

How my node log looks like if i open my dashboard:

```
GET /widgets/time?_=1461141536338 500 9.360 ms - 43  //Here is the culprit
GET /widgets/image?_=1461141536339 200 33.699 ms - - 
GET /widgets/time/js?_=1461141536343 200 65.363 ms - 159 
GET /widgets/quotes?_=1461141536340 200 76.213 ms - - 
GET /widgets/keyvaluelist?_=1461141536341 200 70.368 ms - - 
GET /widgets/calendar?_=1461141536342 200 82.590 ms - - 
GET /widgets/image/js?_=1461141536344 200 13.441 ms - 218 
GET /widgets/quotes/js?_=1461141536345 200 4.452 ms - 497 
GET /widgets/keyvaluelist/js?_=1461141536346 200 4.301 ms - 502 
GET /widgets/calendar/js?_=1461141536347 200 3.261 ms - 721
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.
For a widget you need an .html and .styl file in the widget folder.
This mistake is preventable by using: 
`atlasboard generate widget MYWIDGETNAME`
A widget without HTML will produce the 500 err in the node log.
That was a stupid 7h long bug hunt....